# Why are people asking Stack Overflow questions on Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, meta, off-topic

It's happened quite a few times. [Here's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27011/replacing-whole-html-content-kills-head-and-body-tags-after-http-request) a recent one. So I'm wondering, what is the scenario? Are they scrolling down to the link of sites, clicking meta and posting? Are they googling for some result, that gives them a post on meta and then they ask?

Comment: Because Meta is where all the action is, baby!

Comment: Oh so hilarious, the same user posted right back here after you bring this up.

Comment: Maybe we need an "It looks like your question is about programming" like SO's "the question you're asking appears subjective" warning :)

Comment: Then all those Greasemonkey junkies will have to deal with it and then write up a Greasemonkey to kill that.

Comment: +1 'cuz I was just wondering the same thing myself.

Comment: [Why do users often ask blatantly off-topic questions here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305749/why-do-users-often-ask-blatantly-off-topic-questions-here-on-meta) has updated answers to this question. Note that at the time this question was asked, the site known as Meta Stack Overflow was *this* site; the current Meta Stack Overflow was established in 2014 and this site was renamed from that to its current name.

Answer (score 14):

We need "belongs on Stack Overflow", "belongs on Super User" and "belongs on Server Fault" as close reasons for meta.

Comment: Yes we really do.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to stick with the same answer I gave to the last question I answered:

> People don't read!

*A little warning message on the ask page couldn't hurt too much, though, could it?*

Comment: a little warning message is (at least as of today), and if it doesn't hurt, it for sure doesn't prevent non-readers.

Answer (score 5):

It's revenge posting from that side of the fence.

For far too long they've had to deal with their share of closing and shunting questions such as "[What is Stück Überfloé built with?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with)" and "[Why my question closing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=why+was+my+question+closed)" as not programming and "Belongs on Meta" questions.

They've soldiered up some pawns into the front line to ask programming questions that belong on SO on Meta. They know full well things get stuck here like the veritable black hole of no escape. Velcro could only hope to stick like this.

It's utterly, honey rhythmically scrumptious and delicious to their tastes and delight.

Comment: I consider this a mistreatment of Umlaute! Which does not prevent me form voting this up.

Comment: Please correct for more/apt diacritics as you see fit.

Comment: Then I have nothing to complain about anymore.

Comment: @John Smithers: Umlaut doesn't end in an 'e'. I consider this mistreatment of Germanic typography!

Comment: @Welbog: It is the plural form, French-speaking cretin!

Comment: @John Smithers: Blast! That will teach me to use knowledge from my mostly-forgotten German classes!

Comment: @Welbog: You're always welcome to refresh your knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

In [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49432/when-and-how-did-you-use-inhertiance-in-a-web-project-in-a-very-interesting-way), the OP said it was because the question was *too subjective* for SO

Weird reasoning...

Comment: Sounds like "it's the junkyard" in disguise.